# Mock HttpWebResponse/responder with WebRequest.RegisterPrefix

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, httpwebrequest

I have some code I'm trying to unit test and from what I can tell, it's simply not possible. There are several questions similar to this, some of which incorrectly claim to solve this problem however none them can actually test my product code. Below is a sample of the important lines;

```
            WebRequest req = (WebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            WebResponse resp = (WebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            /*HttpWebResponse httpResp = (HttpWebResponse)resp;

            if (httpResp.StatusCode != (HttpStatusCode)200)
            {
                _log.Error(String.Format("Recieved non-200 status: {0}", httpResp.StatusCode));
                return default(T); // default(T) == null for all reference types
            }*/
```

In the above code, the commented out block is what should actually be in my product. The two lines above it I've had to use in it's palce to make it unit testable.

My mock for unit testing is based my the example [here](http://blog.salamandersoft.co.uk/index.php/2009/10/how-to-mock-httpwebrequest-when-unit-testing/) which says it mocks `HttpWebResponse` but in fact mocks `WebResponse`. From what I can tell it's not possible to mock the `HttpWebResponse` because it's constructors have both been deprecated... Here is an example modifying the code from that blog posting;

```
class TestWebReponse : HttpWebResponse
{
    Stream responseStream;

    /// <summary>Initializes a new instance of <see cref="TestWebReponse"/>
    /// with the response stream to return.</summary>
    public TestWebReponse(Stream responseStream)
    {
        this.responseStream = responseStream;
    }

    /// <summary>See <see cref="WebResponse.GetResponseStream"/>.</summary>
    public override Stream GetResponseStream()
    {
        return responseStream;
    }
}
```

However the above will not compile due to the `HttpWebResponse does not have a constructor that takes 0 arguments` error. Does anyone have a work around for this that employs a similar mechanism for intercepting the product codes request but is capable of returning an `HttpWebResponse`? Mocking `WebResponse` just simply isn't very useful for these types of applications (no rest consumer should be using `WebRequest`/`WebResponse` in favor of `HttpWebRequest`/`HttpWebResponse`) and this is the point at which I must test so using Moq or a similar utility to make one of my methods return the object is not an option, as it would just circumvent the code I'm trying to test (which to be clear is two things; is my request valid and do we correctly deserialize the response). So the only restriction for answers is that the test code needs to remain similar to this;

```
string response = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(expected);
WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("test", new TestWebRequestCreate());
TestWebRequest request = TestWebRequestCreate.CreateTestRequest(response);

var client = new FakeProprietaryHTTPClient();
PropietaryDataType res = client.MakeRequestThatReturnsDeserializedPropietaryDataType();
// do asserts against that PropertaryDataType
```

Comment: have you tried to use [Microsoft Moles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798308.aspx) ? another option is to use [typemock isolator](http://www.typemock.com/isolator-product-page) or [telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/mocking.aspx)... (typemock is better!)

Comment: @OldFox can you elaborate? I don't think Moles will work because you can't instantiate `HttpWebResponse` because it has no constructors. Mocking the type is an alternative to what I'm trying to do but is fundamentally different because the point where I inject fake/test data is different and not where I want it. I don't want to circumvent the http call my code is making, if I do that then I'm losing test coverage for rest contract stuff like the url and qps.

Comment: actually you can instantiate a child class of HttpWebResponse or WebRequest.
see my answer....

Comment: @OldFox I'll give this a try but can you add the necessary using statements and/or a link to the mocking library you're using. As the answer is I gotta Google to figure out where `MockRepository` is coming from.

Comment: You have to a) subclass HttpWebRequest and b) register the "http:" prefix

Comment: @evanmcdonnal I used rhino mock. I added a link to my solution(in my answer).

Comment: @evanmcdonnal have you tried my answer(I added a link to my project)?

Comment: @OldFox sorry, I haven't been able to return to this due to the need to implement product code. Hopefully I will find the time to try your solution this week.

Answer (score 3):

To simulate TestWebRequest, TestWebResponse classs, i'm going to use concept called PartialMock.

With PartialMock you can create an instance from WebRequest, WebResponse and then override some methods.(we usually apply this approach on abstract classes)

```
    class TestWebRequestCreate : IWebRequestCreate
    {

        static WebRequest _nextRequest;
        static readonly object LockObject = new object();

        static public WebRequest NextRequest
        {
            get { return _nextRequest; }
            set
            {
                lock (LockObject)
                {
                    _nextRequest = value;
                }
            }
        }

        public WebRequest Create(Uri uri)
        {
            return _nextRequest;
        }

        public static WebRequest CreateTestRequest(string response)
        {

            var request = MockRepository.GeneratePartialMock<WebRequest>();

            CreateTestWebRequest(request, response);

            NextRequest = request;

            return request;
        }

        private static void CreateTestWebRequest(WebRequest request, string responseStr)
        {
            var requestStream = new MemoryStream();
            request.Stub(x => x.GetRequestStream()).Return(requestStream);
            request.Stub(x => x.Method).PropertyBehavior();
            request.Stub(x => x.ContentType).PropertyBehavior();
            request.Stub(x => x.ContentLength).PropertyBehavior();

            var response = CreateTestWebResponse(responseStr);
            request.Stub(x => x.GetResponse()).Return(response);

        }

        private static WebResponse CreateTestWebResponse(string responseStr)
        {
            var response = MockRepository.GeneratePartialMock<HttpWebResponse>();
            var responseStream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseStr));
            response.Stub(x => x.GetResponseStream()).Return(responseStream);

            return response;
        }
    }
```

now test all classes together:

```
        var response = "my response string here";
        WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("test", new TestWebRequestCreate());
        var request = TestWebRequestCreate.CreateTestRequest(response);

        var url = "test://MyUrl";

        var f = WebRequest.Create(url);

        var responce = f.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

        var stream = responce.GetResponseStream();

        var content = new StreamReader(stream).ReadLine();

        Assert.AreEqual(response, content);
```

with this concept i simulate the inheritance in your link.

**Edit:**

I used [rhino mocks - partial mock](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+Partial+Mocks.ashx) in my example.

[This](https://github.com/OldFox1/FakeHttpWebRequest/) is a link to my solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy to move to HttpClient (which you should of you can), there's a library for describing fake responses using a fluent interface: [MockHttp](https://github.com/richardszalay/mockhttp)

HttpClient is way better designed to handle mocking (and has an object model around almost the entire http spec)

Disclaimer: I'm the author of said library

Comment: Unfortunately I can't move to `HttpClient` since it's only on .NET 4.5. Thanks for the answer though, I'd take your advice if it were a new project.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal - It's only in .NET 4.5 for the BCL version. The NuGet package (which I recommend anyway) targets 4.0

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Mock, but in a project I've been working on, I needed to do some overriding in an ASMX web service that was throwing errors only in production to find out what XML the service was actually streaming back.  In order to do that, I had to create a fresh HttpWebResponse object.  The basic trick is using **Activator.CreateInstance** (which bypasses the fact that the constructor is deprecated).  In my example below, I am able to leverage the fact that I was simply cloning an existing HttpWebResponse object, but the technique would be the same for creating one entirely from scratch.

```
    string sLastXML;

    public string LastXML
    {
        get
        {
            return sLastXML;
        }
    }

    protected override System.Net.WebResponse GetWebResponse(System.Net.WebRequest request)
    {
        // Get the XML Returned
        System.Net.HttpWebResponse oResponse = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        System.IO.Stream oStream = oResponse.GetResponseStream();
        byte[] inStream = new byte[oResponse.ContentLength];
        int iActual = 0;
        while (iActual < oResponse.ContentLength)
        {
            iActual += oStream.Read(inStream, iActual, (int)oResponse.ContentLength - iActual);
        }
        sLastXML = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(inStream);

        // Create new stream
        System.IO.MemoryStream oNewStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        oNewStream.Write(inStream, 0, (int)oResponse.ContentLength);
        oNewStream.Position = 0;

        // Create new response object
        System.Net.HttpWebResponse oNewResponse = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)System.Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(System.Net.HttpWebResponse));
        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo oInfo = oNewResponse.GetType().GetProperty("ResponseStream", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
        oInfo.SetValue(oNewResponse,oNewStream);
        System.Reflection.FieldInfo oFInfo = oNewResponse.GetType().GetField("m_HttpResponseHeaders", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
        oFInfo.SetValue(oNewResponse, oFInfo.GetValue(oResponse));
        oFInfo = oNewResponse.GetType().GetField("m_ContentLength", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
        oFInfo.SetValue(oNewResponse, oFInfo.GetValue(oResponse));
        oFInfo = oNewResponse.GetType().GetField("m_Verb", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
        oFInfo.SetValue(oNewResponse, oFInfo.GetValue(oResponse));
        oFInfo = oNewResponse.GetType().GetField("m_StatusCode", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
        oFInfo.SetValue(oNewResponse, oFInfo.GetValue(oResponse));
        oFInfo = oNewResponse.GetType().GetField("m_StatusDescription", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
        oFInfo.SetValue(oNewResponse, oFInfo.GetValue(oResponse));
        oFInfo = oNewResponse.GetType().GetField("m_IsMutuallyAuthenticated", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
        oFInfo.SetValue(oNewResponse, oFInfo.GetValue(oResponse));
        oFInfo = oNewResponse.GetType().GetField("m_IsVersionHttp11", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
        oFInfo.SetValue(oNewResponse, oFInfo.GetValue(oResponse));
        oFInfo = oNewResponse.GetType().GetField("m_MediaType", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
        oFInfo.SetValue(oNewResponse, oFInfo.GetValue(oResponse));
        oFInfo = oNewResponse.GetType().GetField("m_Uri", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
        oFInfo.SetValue(oNewResponse, oFInfo.GetValue(oResponse));
        oFInfo = oNewResponse.GetType().GetField("m_UsesProxySemantics", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
        oFInfo.SetValue(oNewResponse, oFInfo.GetValue(oResponse));

        oNewResponse.Cookies = oResponse.Cookies;

        return oNewResponse;


    }
```